# Unable to run mysqldbexport with --export=both on windows 10 My SQL 8.0.16

Tags: mysql

I am trying to export data and ddl using the mysqldbexport using the following command

```
   mysqluc> mysqldbexport --server=user:passowrd@localhost:3306 --export=both --bulk-insert world --output-file=D:/mysqldumps/dump2.sql
```

but it throws an error

```
ERROR: Query failed. 1146 (42S02): Table 'mysql.proc' doesn't exist

Execution of utility: 'mysqldbexport --server=root:root@localhost:3306 --export=both --bulk-insert world --output-file=D:/mysqldumps/dump2.sql' ended with return code '1' but no error message was streamed to the standard error, please review the output from its execution.
```

The query with --export=DATA works fine.

I tried to execute mysql_upgrade as some posts suggested but that is also not a feasible option. I get the following error message

```
The mysql_upgrade client is now deprecated. The actions executed by the upgrade client are now done by the server.
To upgrade, please start the new MySQL binary with the older data directory. Repairing user tables is done automatically. Restart is not required after upgrade.
The upgrade process automatically starts on running a new MySQL binary with an older data directory. To avoid accidental upgrades, please use the --upgrade=NONE option with the MySQL binary. The option --upgrade=FORCE is also provided to run the server upgrade sequence on demand.
It may be possible that the server upgrade fails due to a number of reasons. In that case, the upgrade sequence will run again during the next MySQL server start. If the server upgrade fails repeatedly, the server can be started with the --upgrade=MINIMAL option to start the server without executing the upgrade sequence, thus allowing users to manually rectify the problem.
```

Any help is much appreciated?

Comment: What version of MySQL is the data?  Is `mysqldbexport` a newer version?  Do you have and stored procs?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using mysql.proc table skip it, it contain stored procedures and stored functions, so if you don't have any of these you can skip.

```
--skip=skip-objects

Specify objects to skip in the operation as a comma-separated list (no spaces). Permitted values are CREATE_DB, DATA, EVENTS, FUNCTIONS, GRANTS, PROCEDURES, TABLES, TRIGGERS, and VIEWS.
```

So in your case

```
--skip=PROCEDURES,FUNCTIONS
```

If still command need it create dummy one from other mysql server without any record just with schema.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I am just wondering why doesn't the command ignore if these objects are not defined. Are they defined in new tables?

Comment: I think the reason may be program scope, same program is for every situation, that's why they given option to your scenario too. Could be program is not handle this situation intensionally. Please give up vote it works for you.

Comment: File a bug report at bugs.mysql.com, suggesting that if mysqld.proc (or equivalent) is missing that don't complain about dumping stored procs.